Ansible environment lookup does not give content of variable but it is defined
I am trying to query the ORACLE_HOME environment variable, which is gathered via facts gathering.
I try to access it like follows:
- name: Print oracle_home env
  debug:
    msg: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.env','ORACLE_HOME') }}"

But I dont get any result but an empty string.
However if I query the whole ansible_env variable, ORACLE_HOME is specified:
- name: Print ansible_env
  debug:
    msg: "{{ ansible_env }}"

"msg": {
        "BASH_FUNC_mc%%": "() {  . /usr/share/mc/mc-wrapper.sh\n}",
        "COLORTERM": "1",
        "CPU": "x86_64",
        "CSHEDIT": "emacs",
        "CVS_RSH": "ssh",
        "DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS": "unix:path=/run/user/0/bus",
        "FROM_HEADER": "",
        "GPG_TTY": "/dev/pts/0",
        "G_BROKEN_FILENAMES": "1",
        "HISTSIZE": "1000",
        "HOME": "/root",
        "HOST": "XYZ",
        "HOSTNAME": "XYZ",
        "HOSTTYPE": "x86_64",
        "LANG": "POSIX",
        "LC_CTYPE": "en_US.UTF-8",
        "LESS": "-M -I -R",
        "LESSCLOSE": "lessclose.sh %s %s",
        "LESSKEY": "/etc/lesskey.bin",
        "LESSOPEN": "lessopen.sh %s",
        "LESS_ADVANCED_PREPROCESSOR": "no",
        "LIBGL_DEBUG": "quiet",
        "LOGNAME": "root",
        "MACHTYPE": "x86_64-suse-linux",
        "MAIL": "/var/spool/mail/root",
        "MANPATH": "/usr/share/man:/usr/local/man",
        "MINICOM": "-c on",
        "MORE": "-sl",
        "ORACLE_BASE": "/u01/app/oracle",
        "ORACLE_HOME": "/u01/app/oracle/product/18c/xe",
        "ORACLE_SID": "XE",
        "OSTYPE": "linux",
        "PAGER": "less",
        "PATH": "/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/root/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin",
        "PROFILEREAD": "true",
        "PWD": "/root",
        "PYTHONSTARTUP": "/etc/pythonstart",
        "QT_SYSTEM_DIR": "/usr/share/desktop-data",
        "SHELL": "/bin/bash",
        "SHLVL": "2",
        "SSH_TTY": "/dev/pts/0",
        "TERM": "xterm",
        "USER": "root",
        "WINDOWMANAGER": "/usr/bin/icewm-session",
        "XCURSOR_THEME": "DMZ",
        "XDG_CONFIG_DIRS": "/etc/xdg",
        "XDG_DATA_DIRS": "/usr/share",
        "XDG_RUNTIME_DIR": "/run/user/0",
        "XDG_SESSION_CLASS": "user",
        "XDG_SESSION_ID": "21",
        "XDG_SESSION_TYPE": "tty",
        "XKEYSYMDB": "/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/XKeysymDB",
        "XNLSPATH": "/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/nls",
        "_": "/usr/bin/python3.6"

Can someone help me? What am I doing wrong?

From the lookup synopsis, emphasis mine: Allows you to query the environment variables available on the controller when you invoked Ansible. So, while your facts come from the managed node the lookups mostly gets data from the controller.

So how can I access the environment variables from the facts to use them in playbooks?

ansible_env.ORACLE_HOME, simply

Just gather facts with subset env and that would work on Windows too ...

and use ansible_facts.env.ORACLE_HOME afterwards.

The lookup() is evaluated on the Ansible controller, probably not what you need in your use-case.
- name: Print local oracle_home env
  debug:
    msg: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.env','ORACLE_HOME') }}"

You could better use this, if you need the ORACLE_HOME on the target machine(s):
- name: Print remote oracle_home env
  debug:
    msg: "{{ ansible_env.ORACLE_HOME }}"

Note: Your playbook needs either gather_facts: true or ansible.builtin.setup: to have the ansible_facts filled with environment variables.
